# When to use super(type) in python?

Tags: python, super, supertype

When can I use `super(type)`? Not `super(type,obj)` but `super(type)` - with one argument.

Comment: Potentially interesting: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-September/010181.html (and Guido's response: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-September/010182.html) (these are from 2007 though). I also found [this](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~micheles/python/super.pdf), which was a bit confusing, at least to me, but might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, `super(x)` returns an "unbound" descriptor, that is, an object that knows *how* to get data, but has no idea *where*. If you assign `super(x)` to a class attribute and then retrieve it, the descriptor machinery cares for proper binding:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'parent'

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        print 'child'

B.parent = super(B)
B().foo()
B().parent.foo()
```

See http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236278 for details.